# Raspbmc stopped playing XViD files, Android Remote no longer works either

Tags: media, remote

I rebooted to get the latest updates, and now my collection of XViD (MPEG-4/AC3) files won't play at all. They played fine before the update. I've googled for solutions, but nothing applicable to my situation comes up. It plays h.264 without issue though.

Also, the Android remote I've been using for my Xbox XBMC and my RaspBMC has stopped working on the RaspBMC now.

Is there some way I can get the RaspBMC to play the files without a full re-install?

Comment: Updated to include what I thought was an implicit question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the config.txt had `gpu_mem_256=128` concatenated onto the end of the mpeg-2 license code I had added in myself ... sorting that out fixed all the problems.